# How might I express a properly typed message queue in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm exploring how I might write a properly typed message queue in TypeScript, where each topic is identified by a Symbol and has its own message type. I'm looking for something of the form:

```
const names = Symbol('name');
const ages = Symbol('age');
type Name = string;
type Age = number;

type TopicId = Symbol;

interface Messager {
  publish(topic: TopicId, message: any): Promise<boolean>,
  subscribe(topic: TopicId, consumer: (message: any) => Promise<boolean>): void
}

const messager: Messager<NameTopic | AgeTopic> = null;
messager.publish(names, "test-name");
messager.publish(ages, 23);
```

so that the publish and subscribe methods's message types are discriminated by the type of the topic. For example, I would like the `messager` value to be an instance of the `Messager` type which allows strings to published on the `name` topic and numbers to be published on the `age` topic.

This feels like a job for distributed conditional types but I'm afraid the correct syntax eludes me.

Comment: I assume `names` and `ages` are not in scope where `Messager` is defined? E.g., they could be any Symbol?

Comment: The base `Messager` interface should be a generic type whose generic parameter is intended to be the functional equivalent of a map of topics (symbols) to message types. In this example, the `messager` value is intended to be an instance of the `Messager` interface constrained to allow the name topic to publish strings and the age topic to publish numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to define things like this:

```
type Topic = {
  symbol: Symbol;
  type: unknown
}

interface Messager<T extends Topic> {
  publish<S extends T["symbol"]>(
    topic: S,
    message: Extract<T, { symbol: S }>["type"]
  ): Promise<boolean>,
}
```

So a `Topic` is a pair of a symbol and a type.  Then, a `Messager` can be generic in `T`, a union of `Topic` types.  Your methods will be generic in `S`, one of the symbols inside `T` (specifically you are [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `"symbol"` property of `T`, that is, `T["symbol"]`, which will be a union if `T` is a union).

For `publish`, the `topic` parameter is just `S`.  Then we want to constrain the `message` parameter to be the corresponding `"type"` property.  This is where those distributed conditional types come in.  Here I use [`Extract<A, B>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) a utility type that takes a union type `A` and keeps only the members of it which are assignable to `B`.  So if we take `Extract<T, {symbol: S}>`, we should get just the topic where the `"symbol"` property is `S`.  Then we look up its `"type"` property... giving us the type `Extract<T, {symbol: S}>["type"]`.

Let's see it in action:

```
const names = Symbol('name');
type NameTopic = {
  symbol: typeof names;
  type: string
}

const ages = Symbol('age');
type AgeTopic = {
  symbol: typeof ages;
  type: number;
}
```

Here we have the two `Topic` types, `NameTopic` and `AgeTopic`.  The rest of the code proceeds as you wanted:

```
const messager: Messager<NameTopic | AgeTopic> = null!;
messager.publish(names, "test-name"); // okay
messager.publish(names, 100); // error! 100 is not a string
messager.publish(ages, 23); // okay
messager.publish(ages, "NaN") // error! "NaN" is not a number

const shoesizes = Symbol("shoesizes")
messager.publish(shoesizes, 123); // error, not the right symbol
```

Where the compiler enforces that the right value goes with the right symbol.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9mAlgYygXigbwFBSgZxAFsAjOAGwC4oBlYs8gblylEmoFcA7Aay7gDuXbAF9s2RF2AQATgDMAhsmgBZCPnwKA5rIA8MKBAAe0rgBN8sBCgB8WFmA4lyifAAtdNQyYjnLMAG0AIkJSCiCAXRsAChY8YGtkahoAGjioInVNHWoAURMZJWB9FKwCegpkqBEbYLYISJYASmoABRk4IlcIXTIKCAUuGzSxbGQ4LnxgKC4FTMsMOjDyaIByWczVpuZ6qAA5OYh4JFQMHDxQhmp6uDkZw-xmePAIaimZSS1RcXHJ6e11OhaBUVqsAVsdi8oABBHTHFBA87lZbXF63KAAx4serULgcUiyZijX5TDJZAEyahqDQU3QHTLw1AAHxhcMSdgwePI5AAhMx5tlZAA6RzOVxuaIbdSlILSKYAWilQW2UAA9KqoHAeAoQNgBRSRU4XO5JQ9SgBGAAMlpV6sMMg6Mh5UCtlqgrhmcH+BGAHy4X31OhkhrFJsxpQATABmW0arU6vXkoMh40S8NQIIHPbKtUa2SO52ZhTZ92WfjevEEmQ-Cak9xwdSIABegMWIOiITcDfwzfUysTNOTotT0XrjZb+At0dj9sdpXLrDc0A+Wjc00uFHEQA)

Comment: That works an absolute treat, and better yet, I pretty much follow what's going on, though there is almost no chance I would have arrived at this solution on my own.

Two followups ensue. One, is there a resource that you've found helpful for learning more about how to express type transformations?

Another: once I flesh out the rest of the Messager interface, I wind up with several repetitions of the derived message type `Extract<T, { id: S }>['type']`, which is unwieldy and hard to read. Is there a way to assign type symbols to repeated derived types in a scope?

Comment: Two: you can always do `type TypeFrom<T extends Topic, S extends T["symbol"]> = Extract<T, {id: S}>['type']` and then use `TypeFrom<T, S>` everywhere.  As far as I know you can't define type aliases anywhere that will have `T` and `S` already in scope.

Comment: One: Other than reading the [TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) and the [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html) for new versions, I've spent a lot of time following the [issues in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues).  I don't know if I have insight into a *quick* way to learn this stuff, though...

Comment: The further I got into this answer, the more I knew it would end with "jcalz." :-)